# Why are hair particles so patchy?

Tags: particles, hair

I am trying to cover my model in fur but this is the result I get:

[image]

This is my first time and for sure the guide particles are not perfect but I don't think they are so bad either to cause this result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Here are my particle settings:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Turn on *Use Modifier Stack* option

Comment: I turned it on but when I checked the box all the particles disappeared as if I deleted them. That didn't seem right so I started a new project, I have the same problem and I checked the box again, now nothing happened, I guess because there are no other modifiers on the mesh.